# Can conjured creatures act in the round they're conjured in?

Tags: spells, actions, summoning, initiative, anima-beyond-fantasy

Specifically, if someone casts the Create Homunculus (Creation 26) spell, could the homunculus created thusly act immediately?  Taken to extremes, this could well set up a budget grey goo scenario:

1. Person, carrying two items with the Automatic Spell power (Prometheum Exxet) bearing Imitate with an additional charge/Create Homunculus +1 Added Effect, exists and decides they want to bury the world in homunculi and magic items.
2. Using the charge of Create Homunculus on item #1, and buying magic projection on the homunculi, the caster orders the homunculi to activate the two charges of Imitate on the root item, and then activate Create Homunculus on the two items they just produced, and then order the homunculi the homunculi just created to do the exact same thing (recursively), and then get out of the way of the self-replication...

...Well.  That might be a bit of an absurd scenario.  But it's not, as far as I understand things, impossible.

Another, more reasonable example:

3. Caster with, e.g., an item of Create Monstrosity activates it, wants the monstrosity to attack the enemy immediately.  Can the monstrosity do so?

Comment: My apologies for the somewhat incoherent nature of the question as I first posted it.  I came at the question from the direction of "oh crap, would this exploit actually *work?*", because the technique behind it could do an *absurd* amount of nonsense were it to go unchecked...

Comment: This question needs a tag for the game it is for

Comment: @Scott Dunnington it already has a tag for the game it's for.

Answer (score 1):

> Another, more reasonable example:
>
> 1. Caster with, e.g., an item of Create Monstrosity activates it, wants the monstrosity to attack the enemy immediately. Can the
>      monstrosity do so?

At the above example. Yes.
Action limits are your main limitation here. You have to individually order these creatures to do things. Unless given conditional orders (that could be repeated), they do nothing... The copies would have the standing orders from the previous copy though, which could cause issues.

All of these scenario's encourage your GM to use the chapter 26 (page 282) rule allowing them to spend 100-200 DP on these creatures.

Comment: I figure I can script a recursion well enough.

Comment: You have to use your action to order creatures?

Comment: Thats what I said, didnt I?

Comment: Yes, but why did you say it?  Cite please.

Comment: Page 80 of the core book for actions. Anything more complicated than something you can do instantly, basically. If it takes more than 3 seconds to say, it's an active action. Given that your instructions have to be fairly specific, and there is no assumption of intelligence on behalf of the Homonculi. They only do what you tell them to do, nothing more.